# Portrait mode on iPhone 11 vs 11 pro with messy hair

Tags: iphone, photos, camera

So I have messy hair and strands everywhere, and when I take a picture on my iPhone 11 portrait mode it just blurs the strands because of the machine learning algorithm.

Is this the case for an 11 pro? Or would the 3rd camera capture depth properly and know that the messy strands are part of my head?

(I know, silly question)

Comment: I briefly had a 13 Pro Max & it still does it. Tiny extract - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sABnW.png